# What kind of HTTP redirect for logins?

Tags: http, redirect, authentication, http-status-code-302

I'm currently redirecting users to a login page when they try to hit their home page.

For example: `http://www.goals.com/login.php?from=%2Fhome.php`

Unfortunately, I'm also told that 302 redirection hurts SEO, and this type of redirection is showing up as a 302. Is this the correct HTTP status code for this type of redirection, or is there a better practice I should be following?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SEO doesn't matter if the homepage is password protected. Crawlers can't login to see the content, so your concern is moot.

Comment: Great, thanks. I figured this was the case, but wasn't positive. Appreciate the thoughts.